# Alert message not showing after redirecting

Tags: angular

I am using the following plunkr code to show success/error/warning message
after getting success/error/warning message from API call

```
[https://plnkr.co/edit/GmOUPtXYpzaY81qJjbHp?p=preview][1]
```

It is working fine.
but the issue is after showing message i need to navigate to another route.
**while navigating to another route alert code is executing but alert is not displaying 
   alert should display on top of new route

How to handle it.

my code is

EditComponent

```
//some code is missing
this.roomTypeService.editRoomDetials(this.requestedData, this.editData.id)
     .subscribe(suc => this.editBusinessData(suc),
                err => console.log(err));   
//some code is missing

editBusinessData(data) {

    debugger;
    console.log('init', this.businessData.length);
    console.log(data.data);
    let index;
       index = findIndex(this.businessData,  {
         'id' : +(data.data[0].id)
       });
       this.businessData.splice(index, 1);
      console.log(index);
      console.log('after splice', this.businessData.length);
      this.businessData.push(data.data);
      console.log('after adding updated data', this.businessData.length);
      this.customService.setRoomTypesBusinessData(this.businessData);
      this.openDialogBox();
      this.router.navigate(['/clouds/configurations/roomtype/view']);
  }

  openDialogBox() {
   debugger;
    this.dlgProps1.dlgHeader = 'Success';
    this.dlgProps1.msgTxt = 'Record Updated!!';
    this.dlgProps1.okBtn = true;
    this.dlgProps1.cancelBtn = false;
    this.dlgProps1.msgType = 'success';
    this.dlgProps1.setTime = 3000;
    this.dlgProps.emit(this.dlgProps1);
    // console.log(this.dlgProps1, '(((((((');
    this.dialogAnchor.createDialog(DialogComponent);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this,

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 alert alert-success" ng-show="successMessagebool ">
    <strong>{{successMessage }}</strong>
```

**JS**

```
$http.post('/user/userList').then(function (response) {
    $scope.successMessage = "Form submitted successfully";
    $scope.successMessagebool = true;
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.successMessagebool = false;
         window.location = '/user/userList';
    }, 5000);
```

Comment: Hi @Prabaharan Thanks for update... but the alert should not close until the user give some action(ok or cancel)

Comment: @Santhosh Remove the time(5000) and check,it's set to close after 5 secs

Comment: @Pabaharan, i have tried this one, if i remove time alert is closing in some milli seconds(something like blinking)   , alert should not close until user give some action for this i am providing  OK , Cancel Button